# Matplotlib plotting subplots to existing figure

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I'm wondering if there's an equivalent function to

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
```

where only the axes array is generated for an existing figure, instead of creating a new figure object. I basically need to create a matplotlib window, populate it, and update it when a button has been pressed. I would like to use the `subplots` method as it allows sharing axes, but it forces the creation of a new figure object, which would open a new window.

My current code looks like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()

# When button is pressed
fig.clear()
for i in range(6):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 2, i+1)
    ax.plot(x, y)
plt.draw()
```

And I'd like to do something like

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(3, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')

# When button is pressed
fig.clear()
axarr = fig.subplots(3, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(2):
        ax = axarr[i][j]
        ax.plot(x, y)
plt.draw()
```

Alternatively, is there a way to directly work with the matplotlib windows? I could plot the new figure object into the existing window if that is an option as well.

I am using the PySide backend if that makes any difference. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, you either use `fig, axarr = plt.subplots(...)` or create the figure yourself and add the subplots manually.  If I remember correctly, `plt.subplots` is actually adding each new axis for you under the hood in the pyplot source code, i.e. according to your first example.

Comment: Yes but the `subplots` method is able to hide certain axis labels, and also link certain subplots together when the interactive tools such as zoom are used. I'm not sure how to replicate these bevaviours.

Comment: If you want to link two subplots together you can do that with the keyword argument `sharex = ax_???` or `sharey` when you call `add_subplot`.  I.e. `ax2 = fig.add_subplots(2, 1, 2, sharex=ax1)` if ax1 is already created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is implemented on the master branch [via PR#5146](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5146) which is targetted for mpl 2.1 which *should* be out in the fall.

If you need it *now* either run the master branch or vendor that method as a function

```
axarr = vendored_subplots(fig, ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

A dirty workaround:

you can use the keyword `num` to specify the figure handle explicitly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig1, axes1 = plt.subplots(5, 4, gridspec_kw={'top': 0.5}, num=1)
fig2, axes2 = plt.subplots(5, 4, gridspec_kw={'bottom': 0.5}, num=1)
plt.show()
```

This gives:

```
In [2]: fig1 is fig2
Out[2]: True

In [3]: axes1 is axes2
Out[3]: False
```

All subplot parameters have to be given to the `grispec_kw` and `subplot_kw` arguments in the beginning. They can't be change easily afterwards anymore.