# How do I add a subplot to an existing figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

Consider that I have a pre-existing figure like:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
```

[image]

How can I add a 5th subplot that would take both rows in a third column?

I know it's easy to create such a figure from the start using, for example, mosaics like

```py
plt.figure().subplot_mosaic([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 3]])
```

which produces what I want:

[image]

But the figure comes from an existing application, and if I were to replicate the same figure manually it'd take a huge amount of code. So really I'd need a way to do it *after* the first 4 subplots are already built and plotted.

Can this be done? (Preferably with `constrained_layout` active, although I'm sure this would be asking too much.)

PS: I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231738/matplotlib-plotting-subplots-to-existing-figure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63703979/append-subplots-to-existing-figure-in-matplotlib), but I couldn't make them work for what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new axes by firstly adjusting current plots, then putting new axes at a specified position.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.7 )
ax2 = fig.add_axes((0.75, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8))
plt.show()
```

Here I set the right border of an existing graph at 0.7 in relative units, then put new axis within a rectangle: (left, bottom, width, height) in relative units. Use ax2.plot() for adding data on new axes. It messes up layout, but I don't know how to counter that. If it's opened in terminal, however, looks ok in fullscreen (picrelated)
[image: New figure, 'inline']
[image: New figure, 'fullscreen']